# How do I take a value from a list and iterate over a separate string to find the indices where the value is present?

Tags: python, string, list, iteration

I have a list as below:

```
a_list=['i']
```

I also have this string:

```
a_string='i dont know where i belong but i know i am okay here'
```

How would I iterate over the string to find each index where the list term occurs? I was thinking of doing linear search but I am already within a function and can't figure out how to import the list from the outer function to the nested function where I would define the linear search.

Edit: I found the answer to this after some time. I was simply unsure of how functions could work in other functions. I was worried that nesting functions within each other could lead to errors.

Comment: *"import the list from the outer function"*? What do you mean exactly? Please [edit] and add your code. Otherwise, this is a duplicate of [Find all the occurrences of a character in a string](/q/13009675/4518341) or [How to find all occurrences of a substring?](/q/4664850/4518341) BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach will be to to iterate the string using `enumerate`, and take the index whenever value matches:

```py
>>> [i for i,v in enumerate(a_string) if v==a_list[0]]
[0, 18, 31, 38]
```

I'm taking the first value in above iteration using `a_list[0]` but you can easily add another loop for multiple values in `a_list`

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the index of the WORD in the sentence then you can split the sentence into a list:

```
>>> a_string='i dont know where i belong but i know i am okay here'
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(a_string.split(' ')) if x == "i"]
[0, 4, 7, 9]
```